# MySQL UNION - combining the returned values into one set of rows

Tags: mysql, union

I am new to MySQL and need to ask for your help please.
I am selecting 2 sets of count values from the same table in 2 parts of a union using different WHERE clause values to differentiate; like this:

```
SELECT Count(column1) as 'RED', null as 'BLUE'
FROM TableA
Where column1 Like 'RED'
UNION
SELECT NULL, Count(column1)
FROM TableA
Where column1 Like 'BLUE'
```

I was hoping to get:

```
RED      BLUE
---      ----
23       55
```

But what I actually get is:

```
RED      BLUE
---      ----
23       NULL
NULL     55
```

Can anyone please tell me what I've done wrong and how I can get my desired answer please?
Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 3):

That is not a good use case for `UNION`. You can accomplish what you are trying to do using `SUM` and `CASE`. Here's an example using your query:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN column1 LIKE 'RED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS red_count,
SUM(CASE WHEN column1 LIKE 'BLUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS blue_count
FROM TableA
WHERE column1 LIKE 'RED'
OR column1 LIKE 'BLUE'
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the query you need

```
select
    A.colorcount RED,
    B.colorcount BLUE
from
    (select count(1) colorcount from tableA where column1='RED') A,
    (select count(1) colorcount from tableA where column1='BLUE') B
;
```

Here is sample data

```
mysql> drop database if exists encue;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> create database encue;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> use encue
Database changed
mysql> create table tableA
    -> (
    ->     id int not null auto_increment,
    ->     column1 varchar(20),
    ->     primary key (id),
    ->     key (column1)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)

mysql> insert into tableA (column1) values
    -> ('RED'),('BLUE'),('BLUE'),('BLUE'),('RED'),('BLUE'),
    -> ('RED'),('BLUE'),('BLUE'),('BLUE'),('RED'),('BLUE'),
    -> ('RED'),('BLUE'),('BLUE'),('BLUE'),('RED'),('BLUE'),
    -> ('RED'),('BLUE'),('BLUE'),('BLUE'),('RED'),('BLUE'),
    -> ('RED'),('BLUE'),('BLUE'),('BLUE'),('RED'),('BLUE'),
    -> ('RED'),('BLUE'),('BLUE'),('BLUE'),('RED'),('BLUE'),
    -> ('RED'),('BLUE'),('BLUE'),('BLUE'),('RED'),('BLUE'),
    -> ('RED'),('BLUE'),('BLUE'),('BLUE'),('RED'),('BLUE'),
    -> ('RED'),('BLUE'),('BLUE'),('BLUE'),('RED'),('BLUE'),
    -> ('RED'),('BLUE'),('BLUE'),('BLUE'),('RED'),('BLUE'),
    -> ('RED'),('BLUE'),('BLUE'),('BLUE'),('RED'),('BLUE'),
    -> ('BLUE'),('BLUE'),('BLUE'),('BLUE'),('BLUE'),('BLUE'),
    -> ('BLUE'),('BLUE'),('BLUE'),('BLUE'),('BLUE'),('RED');
select count(1) colorcount,column1 from tableA group by column1;
Query OK, 78 rows affected (0.10 sec)
Records: 78  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select count(1) colorcount,column1 from tableA group by column1;
+------------+---------+
| colorcount | column1 |
+------------+---------+
|         55 | BLUE    |
|         23 | RED     |
+------------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is the output you are looking for :

```
mysql> select A.colorcount RED,B.colorcount BLUE from
    -> (select count(1) colorcount from tableA where column1='RED') A,
    -> (select count(1) colorcount from tableA where column1='BLUE') B
    -> ;
+-----+------+
| RED | BLUE |
+-----+------+
|  23 |   55 |
+-----+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
SELECT Count(column1) as red, null as blue
FROM TableA Where column1 Like 'RED'
UNION
SELECT NULL as red, Count(column1) as blue
FROM TableA Where column1 Like 'BLUE'
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL statement

```
SELECT Count(A.column1) as red, Count(B.column1) as blue FROM TableA as A,  TableA as B Where A.column1 Like 'RED' AND B.column1 Like 'BLUE'
```